# Float text towards left using shape-outside - CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to float text to left, I would like to have text under my triangle. How can I do that?

```css
.content {
   background-color: #fff;
   min-height: 320px;
   min-width: 320px;
   max-width: 600px;
   text-align: justify;
}

.content::before {
   float: left;
   display: block;
   content: '';
   height: 0;
   border: 150px solid #dcdcdc;
   border-right-color: transparent;
   border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae debitis dignissimos, voluptatem quas, quo aliquid
      veniam illo itaque doloribus, sequi exercitationem tempore obcaecati cum consectetur blanditiis natus at. Dicta
      nobis eum provident quasi atque cum eveniet, voluptas adipisci fugit esse.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci dolorem assumenda, 
   </div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Already posted an answer, but now that I read it again I am not sure if I understand you correctly. @Paulie_D is right.

Comment: I suspect this might be a `shape-outside` issue,

Comment: Yeah I guess too!

Comment: Thanks for help! This is work: shape-outside: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 100%); :)

Comment: No worries! I will update the question for future reference. Happy coding!.

Comment: in addtion to the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55034678/8620333 (I cannot add it to the list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `shape-outside` property especially `polygon` to fix the issue:

[reference](https://codeburst.io/mastering-css-series-shape-outside-44d626270b25)

```css
.content {
  background-color: #fff;
  min-height: 320px;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.content::before {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  border: 150px solid #dcdcdc;
  float: left;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 0% 100%);
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 0%, 0% 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae debitis dignissimos, voluptatem quas, quo aliquid veniam illo itaque doloribus, sequi exercitationem tempore obcaecati cum consectetur blanditiis natus at. Dicta nobis eum provident quasi
  atque cum eveniet, voluptas adipisci fugit esse. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci dolorem assumenda,
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that in various ways. One of the proper ways in my opinion would be to use a background gradient.

```css
.content {
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: justify;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 50%, white 50.25%), /* update direction and start/stop value to your needs */
  linear-gradient(90deg, #dcdcdc, #dcdcdc) white;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae debitis dignissimos, voluptatem quas, quo aliquid veniam illo itaque doloribus, sequi exercitationem tempore obcaecati cum consectetur blanditiis natus at. Dicta nobis eum provident quasi
  atque cum eveniet, voluptas adipisci fugit esse. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci dolorem assumenda,
</div>
```

*Note: I removed some of your CSS properties (like `min_width` or `max-width`) so you can see that this solution is fully responsive. You can, of course, just add them back.*

Comment: I think task is to make something with content (text), not with triangle. How to fit text under triangle (something like float, but in this case not working, because real size of box with triangle is 300 x 300). It has to fitting when resize website.

Comment: Look at this link. You have before and after effect. 
https://github.com/devmentor-pl/practice-html-and-css-rwd/tree/master/01